# If one stays in an AirBnB for which subletting is not allowed, is it your problem?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, breach-of-contract

This question is based on [this consumer affairs problem on the Guardian site](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2022/jul/14/during-a-stay-with-airbnb-we-were-told-the-let-was), but the details are not explicit so I shall present a hypothetical:

- Alice owns a house
- Bob lets the house from Alice, with a clause in the contract that specifically excludes the subletting of the property
- Charlie sublets the house from Bob via AirBnB in breach of this contract
- During Charlie's stay at the house, Alice approaches Charlie, informs them of the lack of permission to sublet and:

  - Demands additional payment to remain in the house
  - Demands Charlie leave the property before the end of their planned stay
  - Threatens to call the police if one or other of the above demands are not met

What is Charlie's legal situation here?  Is there any requirement for them to pay Alice anything?  Do they have the right to remain in the property?  Have they done anything the police may consider a crime?  Could they have a case against Alice for threatening behaviour?

I would have assumed that Bob has breached a contractual term with Alice, generating a potential civil case against him.  I cannot see that this would affect Charlie at all, but I do not know.

Comment: I don't know about united kingdom, but in other jurisdictions, such a clause would be void by itself. In Switzerland, the owner must not generally forbid subletting. So if Alice threw Bob out for alleged breach of contract, she would be liable for Bobs extra expenses.

Comment: @PMF In England and Wales, if not elsewhere in the UK, it is common for tenancy agreements to forbid tenants from subletting the whole of the property without consent from the landlord. Also, it is common for mortgages, insurances and leaseholds to forbid sublets.

Comment: In the US it is common for a lease to require the landlord's approval for a sublease or sublet, and not uncommon for a rental agreement to prohibit any sublets.  Such agreements are lawful and enforceable in many US jurisdictions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Charlie is not a party to the contract between Alice and Bob

Alice and Charlie have no contractural relationship and Alice cannot require him to do anything nor is he liable to Alice in any way.

Alice’s issue is with Bob who has clearly breached his contract. Alice can sue Bob for damages and *may* be able to end the lease.

There is no trespass because Charlie is there with the permission of the leaseholder. From Charlie’s position there is no reason to believe that Bob does not have the authority to give this permission so Charlie is not in breach of the law. The police will see this as a civil matter and won’t intervene.

Comment: "There is no trespass because Charlie is there with the permission of the leaseholder." - Bob was not capable of giving Charlie permission.

Comment: @Lag of course Bob can. It’s just a breach of contract for him to do so. That doesn’t make the permission invalid, it just allows Alice to sue Bob.

Comment: It seems in March 2019 you had the same opinion as I do now. "The guest does not have permission because the host lacked the authority to give it to them." https://law.stackexchange.com/a/38381/17893

Answer (score -2):

Charlie is trespassing, a civil wrong. Charlie commits a criminal offence ([s144 Legal Aid, Sentencing and Punishment of Offenders Act 2012](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2012/10/section/144/enacted)) if he refuses to leave Alice's property after she has told him to leave. Alice is free to call the police.

I don't think Alice is free to allow Charlie to stay because of her tenancy agreement with Bob. But either way her insurance, [leasehold](https://www.standard.co.uk/homesandproperty/property-news/letting-out-a-flat-through-airbnb-do-i-need-permission-to-sublet-my-flat-to-holidaymakers-and-who-do-i-need-to-ask-a135251.html) and/or [mortgage agreement](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2016/apr/02/airbnb-guests-cost-you-your-home-breach-mortgage-terms) may forbid her from allowing Charlie to stay, whatever the tenancy agreement says.

I don't think Alice is committing a criminal offence if she says to Charlie something along the lines of, "You can stay for £X a night."

With regard to Bob, you point out that Bob is in breach of his tenancy agreement with Alice. Alice might [evict him and seek possession](https://www.gov.uk/evicting-tenants/section-21-and-section-8-notices).

Comment: This answer seems pretty obviously incorrect, so it might be improved with some sources for the key assertions, specifically for the assertion that Charlie is trespassing. Why can't Bob give Charlie permission to be on the property?

Comment: @bdb484 In the question, second bullet point: "Bob lets the house from Alice, with a clause in the contract that specifically excludes the subletting of the property"

Comment: @Lag Bob may not sublet (parts of) the house, but he may clearly allow someone else to be in the house. A passage in Alice and Bobs contract that said something like "It is not allowed to have guests in the house" would most certainly be void.

Comment: @PMF The scenario explicitly described by the question is that (bullet three) Bob tries to sublet to Charlie, which (bullet two) is in breach of Bob's tenancy agreement that forbids him from subletting. Charlie isn't an ordinary guest such as a relative, friend or intimate relationship, he is a paying customer.

Comment: @Lag Sure, but since he's there with the explicit permission of Bob, he's not illegally in that house. If Bob called a doctor to his house, the doctor is also not his friend, and economically speaking it's a business relationship.

Comment: @PMF I don't think Bob is capable of giving permission to Charlie to _rent the whole house_ because of the circumstances described by the question. I have not claimed that Bob is forbidden from inviting one or more people or a doctor etc to visit his dwelling or even stay overnight.

Comment: Maybe he is not, but still, as pointed out in the other answer, Charlie has not done anything wrong. He is there with permission (maybe for longer than what Bob could allow, but still). As long as he behaves as expected, Alice can't do much about it.

Comment: @PMF certainly seems to be correct. Even if Bob has no right to sublet, it seems indisputable that he has the right to admit Charlie onto the property. As long as he has the leaseholder's permission to be on the property, Charlie is not trespassing. Again, it might be useful to provide some sources supporting your assertion that someone can trespass despite having the leaseholder's permission to be on the property.

Comment: Bdb484 quite possible that Bob is incapable of giving permission to enter _with the intent to breach his contract_. If the lease contract says “no drug dealing” he might be incapable of giving a customer permission to enter.